# Is the commutator of two unitary operators normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Given two dxd unitary operators $U,V$, is $[U,V]$ normal? I was able to show it for the d=2 case by direct calculation, but not sure about the general case.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on random 3x3 unitary matrices and found many pairs whose commutators aren't normal. In particular, this is true for the following pair:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1& 1\\
1& e^{i 2\pi/3} & e^{-i2 \pi/3}\\
1 & e^{-i2 \pi/3} & e^{i 2 \pi/3}
\end{bmatrix},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 +i & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-i)& 0\\
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}& 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & i & 1-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix},
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Thoughts:** Hopefully this leads someone else to an answer

We find that
$$
[U,V]^* = (UV - VU)^* = V^*U^* - U^*V^*
$$
So that
$$
[U,V][U,V]^* = (UV - VU)(V^*U^* - U^*V^*) =\\
2I - UVU^*V^* - VUV^*U^*
$$
Similarly, calculate
$$
[U,V]^*[U,V] = 2I - U^*V^*UV - V^*U^*VU
$$
So, $[U,V]$ will be normal iff
$$
UVU^*V^* + VUV^*U^* = U^*V^*UV + V^*U^*VU \iff\\
[UVU^*V^*] + [UVU^*V^*]^* = [U^*V^*UV] + [U^*V^*UV]^* \iff\\
[UVU^*V^* - U^*V^*UV] = [V^*U^*VU - VUV^*U^*] \iff\\
[UV,U^*V^*] = [V^*U^*,VU] \iff\\
[UV,U^*V^*] = - [UV,U^*V^*]^*
$$

Comment: Any developments?

Comment: No. I could put a bounty on the question, if you think it'll help

Comment: Nvm I found a counterexample. See my answer.